# How can I programmatically create a Plexus container for Maven?

Tags: maven

I've written a part of a Maven plugin, but it can no longer run as a plugin. It have access to SCM, or any pom.xml, just an artifact repository and some Maven coordinates. It is meant to take Maven coordinates and print out their dependencies (performing some reporting on them). To do this it needs programmatic access to (for example):

- MavenProjectBuilder
- DependencyGraphBuilder

The usual stuff you'd injected into a mojo, but it's not a mojo and cannot be run as such (as I don't have a pom.xml).

The code I have hasn't helped me, e.g. AbstractMojoTestCase requires a pom.xml, something I don't have.

I'd like some code like..

```
    DefaultPlexusContainer container = new DefaultPlexusContainer();
    Context context = container.getContext();
    context.put("plexus", new DefaultPlexusContainer());
    container.initialize();
    container.start();

    MavenProjectBuilder mavenProjectBuilder = (MavenProjectBuilder) container.lookup(MavenProjectBuilder.ROLE);
    DependencyGraphBuilder dependencyGraphBuilder = (DependencyGraphBuilder) container.lookup(DependencyGraphBuilder.class.getName());
    MavenProject project = mavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(artifact, remoteArtifactRepositories, localRepository);
    // do stuff with dependencies
```

But there's something missing. Help!

Comment: It sounds like you need something like maven-invoker-plugin to create a real maven environment which can be used for integration testing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at how it's done https://github.com/jenkinsci/lib-jenkins-maven-embedder (we use that  in jenkins for similar purpose)